# Sum of checkboxes values and number boxes

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble trying that this script sums, on the one hand, the values of all the marked checkboxes (all with name="PV". The sum should be "PV1"), and on the other hand, the values manually written in the relevant input number boxes (all with name="pvo". The sum should be PV2). After that, with those values it should calculate other numbers (PB1 and PB2). However it doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var PV = document.getElementsByName("PV")
var PVO = document.getElementsByName("pvo")
var PV1 = document.getElementById("PV1")
var PV2 = document.getElementById("PV2")
var PB1 = document.getElementById("PB1")
var PB2 = document.getElementById("PB2")

function clickCh(form){calcpv(this.form) ; calcpvo(this.form) ; calculate(this.form)}

function trunc(n){return ~~n; }

function calcpv(form){for(i=0 ; i < PV.length ; i++)
{if(PV[i].checked == true) {PV1.value += Number(PV[i].value)} }}

function calcpvo(form){for(i=0 ; i < PVO.length ; i++)
{PV2.value += Number(PVO[i].value=)} }

function calculate(form){if(PV1>PV2){PB1.value = trunc(10 + (PV1.value*1 - PV2.value*1 -1)/150)}
else {PB1.value = trunc(10 + (PV1.value*1 - PV2.value*1 +1)/150)}; PB2.value = 20 - PB1.value
}


</script>
```

A relevant sample of my HTML code (there are many table rows similar to this one)

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="PV" value=70>
<input type="checkbox" name="PV" value=70>
<input type="checkbox" name="PV" value=70>
<input type="checkbox" name="PV" value=70></td>
<td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="number" name="pvo"></td></tr>
<input id="PV1" type="text" name="" readonly="readonly">
<input id="PV2" type="text" name="" readonly="readonly">
<input type="button" onclick="clickCh(this.form)" value="calcular"><br>
<input id="PB1" type="text" name="" readonly="readonly">
<input id="PB2" type="text" name="" readonly="readonly"><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use jQuery than it will easy thing:

```
$('input[name=PV]:checked').each(function(){

/// do calculation here.

});
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't know how to use JQuery or even if my client's browsers will support it.

Comment: Ya almost all browser support it. Don't tell me your client is using ie 1 or 2 or 3 hahaha

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong:
You seem to be referencing an array that doesn't exist.

```
if(PV[i].checked == true)
```

I believe you mean to check this:

```
if("PV" + i.checked == true)
```

Comment: I defined the variable PV earlier. Still I tried your solution and some variations around it and still doesn't work.

Comment: problem is in this line I think
for(i=0 ; i < PVO.length ; i++){PV2.value += Number(PVO[i].value=)}